# Printing a string if the string hasn't been printed yet

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to CS and programming and I am trying to create a program made to analyze transaction text files and show some statistics for them. At the moment I am saving all the transactions to a vector, and use a nested for loop to find out how many times that the member appears in the vector. I am now trying to print the quantity in which it appears, but only in the event that the quantity has not already been printed before in the loop. The name of the vector which stores the transaction file is named _Items and the transaction file is written as the following:

```
1:1:water:0:Fri Apr 30 23:47:14 2021
1:1:water:0:Fri Apr 30 23:47:14 2021
1:7:onionsoup:6:Fri Apr 30 23:47:14 2021
1:7:onionsoup:6:Fri Apr 30 23:47:14 2021
1:7:onionsoup:6:Fri Apr 30 23:47:14 2021
```

The code for the class function is written below:

```
void Transactions::itemSales() {
    int Quantity;
    string displayMessage;
    vector<string> _Check;
    cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i <_Items.size(); i++){
            Quantity = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < _Items.size(); j++) {
                    if(_Items[i]._itemNo == _Items[j]._itemNo) {
                            Quantity++;
                    }
            }

            displayMessage =
            std::to_string(_Items[i]._itemNo) + '-' +
             _Items[i]._itemDescription + "'s Quantity sold: " +
             std::to_string(Quantity);

            _Check.push_back(displayMessage);

            for(int k = 0; k < _Check.size(); k++) {
                    if(displayMessage.compare(_Check[k]) != 0) {
                            cout << displayMessage << endl;
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

I would like for the code to be able to show the display message for 1 item number, and then move onto whatever item number is next present in the array.

Comment: Are the items always in sequence like that or can the be mixed up?

Comment: "if the string hasn't been printed yet" sounds like a state you should track.  tracking might be done in a set and unordered_set or a more efficient structure (such as tracking a single number) if they are not mixed up.  For example if items are numbered: 11133322, you can print when number changes; 1112211133 you can print on number increase.  however if they are random, you need to track them individually.

Comment: Move this._Check.push_back(displayMessage); below the search, replace the search with std::find, or std::set as container

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort _Items by itemNo. You can use any sorting algorithm but for the sake of understanding I am implementing bubblesort for you.

```
void sort(_Items arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)     
      
    // Last i elements are already in place 
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) 
        if (arr[j]._itemNo > arr[j+1]._itemNo) 
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
} 

void swap(_Items *small, _Items *big) 
{ 
    _Items temp = *small; 
    *small = *big; 
    *big = temp; 
}
```

After this pass the sorted _Items of list to your items sales method